# Play Framework HTML Form Handling with float value

Tags: html, scala, playframework, sorm

I am trying to develop a small web application using Scala with Play framework.
It has a model called Product which contains a field **price** of type **Float**.

What is the best way to accept the float value through HTML form and save it in the test DB?
I am using sorm as test db.

Comment: You should really use `BigDecimal` for monetary amounts instead of `Float`.

Answer (score -1):

I see you have your model defined which looks like:
  `case class Product(price: Long)`

Also, you will have form which may look like following:

```
val productForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "price" -> longNumber(minLength = 2, maxLength = 10)
    )(Product.apply)(Product.unapply)
  )
```

There are two parts of your questions:

1. Accepting data (best way to accept the float value from HTML form).
2. Persisting data (save it to test db)

### Accepting data and storing it

You have html form for the user to submit data. Now you need to write action to validate data and if its valid push to db or show error messages. Here, you can do something like following:

```
def save = Action { implicit request =>
    productForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errors => BadRequest(views.html.product.create(errors)),
      data => {
        //insert data and redirect to listing view so that he can see the new data
        productCollection.insert(data)
        Redirect(routes.product.list())
          .withNewSession
      }
    )
  }
```

### Adding DB Configuration

Play has support for H2 in-memory database, incase you dont want to use this you can add your own db configuration by commenting the following lines:

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
  db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
```

and adding details below:

```
db.default.user=user
  db.default.password=qwerty
  db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/"
  db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
```

- You will also have to add dependency in project/Build.scala